# How to write linq query on between

Tags: linq

Sql Query

```
select * from Employees where Salary between 1 and 4000
```

How to convert this statement into linq query.

Comment: In the same way that you would convert it to a condition without "between" - i.e. with >= and <= operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for sure:

```
var result = db.Employees.Where(d => d.Salary >= 1 && d.Salary <= 4000);
```

Comment: The casting to *int* shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: neither should the `from` keyword

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved as following, considering Employees contains all the employees (for instance populated by Entity Framework):

```
Employees.Where(e => e.Salary >= 1 && e.Salary <= 4000)
```